# Grey out a selectInput choice after clicking a checkboxInput - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to grey out a selectInput choice from the dropdown after selecting it from the dropdown and clicking a checkboxInput. Below is some example code where I use shinyjs::disable. However, the disable function disables the whole selectInput before I have even selected the checkbox. I would like the selectInput current **choice** to be disabled after the checkbox is selected:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("name","Pick Name:",c("Alice","Austin"),selected = "Alice"),
      br()
      ,width = 3),

    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(

        tabPanel(
          "Tab",
          br(),
          checkboxInput("complete","Complete?"),
          br()
        )

      )

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   observeEvent(input$complete, shinyjs::disable("name"))

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Also, does anyone know how this functionality can be applied across multiple sessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the select options we can using `shinyWidgets` package and its `pickerinput`, such as:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

names <- c("Alice","Austin","Alex")

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            pickerInput("myname","Pick Name:",choices = names),
            br(),width = 3),

        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel(
                    "Tab",
                    br(),
                    checkboxInput("complete","Complete?",FALSE),
                    br()
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

    observeEvent(input$complete, {
        print(input$complete)
        disabled_choices <- names==c("Alex")
        updatePickerInput(
            session = session, inputId = "myname",
            choices = names,
            choicesOpt = list(
                disabled = disabled_choices,
                style = ifelse(disabled_choices,
                               yes = "color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);",
                               no = "")
            )
        )
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Great so this'll grey out the checkbox across all user sessions? I actually need to grey out the dropdown options in the selectInput that have been selected by other users of the same app.

Comment: See example above

Comment: Great this is fantastic! Do you know if this will update the sliderInput choices across multiple sessions of the application?